# Using SWIG with methods that take std::string as a parameter

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I used SWIG to wrap my c++ class. Some methods have a `const std::string&` as a parameter. SWIG creates a type called `SWIGTYPE_p_std__string` however you cannot just pass a normal string for this when invoking the method in c#. The below example is just a modified example that comes with the SWIG package.:

```
public void setName(SWIGTYPE_p_std__string name) 
{
    examplePINVOKE.Shape_setName(swigCPtr, SWIGTYPE_p_std__string.getCPtr(name));
    if (examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
}
```

In my interface file I just have:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "example.h"
```

And the method that is being wrapped in C++ is:

```
void Shape::setName(const std::string& name)
{
    mName = name;
}
```

Is there some sort of typemap I have to put in the interface file? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was trying to solve this myself when I found your question.

You need to include

```
%include "std_string.i"
```

in your `.i` file. See:

- [STL/C++ library](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library)

  for more details.